# Ошибки в библиотеке GLM (C++ Builder)

Tags: c++, opengl, c++builder

При подключении библиотеки GLM возникают ошибки:[image: Ошибки компиляции]

Подключенные библиотеки:

```
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glaux.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <math.h>
```

Версия библиотеки: 0.9.6.3
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, в чем проблема

Comment: Возможно ваша библиотека не адаптирована под borland c++, смотрите внимательно текст, вам же пишется Earlier (ранее) и Мultiply(дубль) - эти строчки рядом, и есть "конфликтные" места (двойное обьявление). Пробуйте разрешить конфликт через #define, если совсем нет - или переписывайте библиотеку подправляя то что не нравится borland, или поищите другую версию библиотеки.

Comment: Body allways defined - Двойная реализация функции - где-то у вас задвоение.

Comment: Возможно ваш setup надо обвернуть (или неверно, недоконца обвернут) в `#ifndef setup_hpp`  `#define setup_hpp` и  `#endif` борланд при добавлении ф-ции создаёт реализацию за   `#endif`, а она должна быть внутри конструкции.